# Save xml file at path given by the user and load it from there again

Tags: c#, xml, filepath

I'm trying to learn how to save date in xml-files and already can do it when I provide the path (eg. C:\Users\Name\Documents) in the code itself. But I want the user to choose the file path once when he opens the program the first time and then use this file path forever.

By now I'm that far:

```
string xmlFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\ToDoList\\xmlList.xml";
XmlTextWriter xWriteList = new XmlTextWriter(xmlFilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Then I have a whole bunch of writing commands which all work well. Just to clarify my problem:
When it says "C:\Users and so on in my sample code, I want the file path the user selected once.
I know I can let the user select a file path with the FileDialog, but I don't know how to save this path somehow. Obviously I can't save it in a xml again because the user would have to choose that path again.

I hope you understand my question and thank everybody who answers in advance.

Comment: Well where did you have in mind that you wanted to save this path? Your settings file? A database? The registry?

Comment: actually, I don't care. it's just that I'm a beginner in c# and just learning how to save data in files. I started with xml-files and just came over the problem I tried to explain above. It like to have it as easy as possible, because I just know xml yet, nothing about setting files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the file from the [`SaveFileDialog.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) property and save it in a class variable.

That will persist it while the program is running.

To persist this between sessions you need to save it somewhere on the users hard drive. You can do this by using an application [configuration or settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Set up a string property in this and then save the chosen filename to that.

On loading:

```
globalFileName = Properties.Settings.Default.FileName;
```

On closing the application:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.FileName = globalFileName;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: thanks. but how can i determine the place where I should save this configuration file? I would take any path if I knew that that one existed on the users computer.

Comment: @user1953145 - the file is sometimes saved in the same folder as the executable is run from, or more often a location in the \Users folder. The location is automatically generated.

Comment: It is basically what I need. But when I use the FolderBrowserDialog (what i want to do) it gives an error. I guess that's because that dialog gives back something like C:\ and i need something like c:\\. How can I solve this?

Comment: @user1953145 - the double slash is only needed when you define the string in code as the slash is a control character and needs to be "escaped". If the string comes back from a system call it's in the right format and doesn't need the double slash.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a `ApplicationSettingsBase` derived setting.

```
    //Application settings wrapper class 
    sealed class FormSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
    {
        [UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return (string )(this["FilePath"]); }
            set { this["FilePath"] = value; }
        }
    }
```

used like this:

```
<on form load handler>
frmSettings1 = new FormSettings();
if(frmSettings1.FilePath==null)
{
    frmSettings1.FilePath = PromptForLocation();
}

<form exit handler>
frmSettings1.Save();
```

where `PromptForLocation` well. Prompts for a location, using, like you " can let the user select a file path with the `FileSaveDialog`"

It should be noted that this will provide a "per user" setting, that gets stored in the user profile directory. If another user logs on, they get their own copy of this setting.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a settings file, and it can be an XML file.  A settings file that is *private* to your program.  It will always be in the same place, so your program knows where it is.  It also can be user specific.

I create a class library to include in all my company projects, it has a class file, the company name, so its obviously about the company's location in the Program Files directory, and in the Common directory to store settings and the User's directory to store settings.

So, I'll show those three, but the one you will want will either be the User's settings directory or the Common.  The problem with using the Program's directory is that it may be in `C:\Program Files` and the operating system won't let you write there unless your program is running as Admin.

The Common directory & files:

```
public const string Company = "YourCompanyName";

/// <summary>
/// Common to all users Company data directory.
/// </summary>
public static DirectoryInfo CommonDataDirectory
{
    get
    {
        string env = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
        string path = Path.Combine(env, Company);
        return new DirectoryInfo(path);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Common to all users data file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static FileInfo CommonDataFile(params string[] path)
{
    string fullName = Paths.Combine(CommonDataDirectory.FullName, path);
    return new FileInfo(fullName);
}
```

The user's settings directory:

```
/// <summary>
/// User's common data directory
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static DirectoryInfo UserDataDirectory
{
    get
    {
        string env = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string path = Path.Combine(env, Company);
        return new DirectoryInfo(path);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// File in user's common data directory
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filename"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static FileInfo UserDataFile(params string[] path)
{
    return new FileInfo(Paths.Combine(UserDataDirectory.FullName, path));
}
```

The program directory: (Where the program/executable is running from)

```
public static DirectoryInfo ProgramDirectory
{
    get
    {
        string executablePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
        return new DirectoryInfo(executablePath);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get's the file in the exectuable's directory, which would be
/// ProgramFiles/applicationName/filename
/// </summary>
public static FileInfo ProgramFile(params string[] path)
{
    string file = Paths.Combine(ProgramDirectory.FullName, path);
    return new FileInfo(file);
}
```

Here's the [Paths class](https://gist.github.com/ChuckSavage/4750630) referenced in the above code.

One other thing, you will want to create a subdirectory from these for your specific program.  So that your different programs can have files with the same name `like Settings.xml` and not conflict with each-other.

I have an ApplicationBase class that uses the Company class for Application specific locations.  Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// The application's name
/// </summary>
public static string ApplicationName
{
    get { return System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Common to all users, application's data directory.
/// </summary>
public static DirectoryInfo CommonDataDirectory
{
    get
    {
        string fullName = Path.Combine(Company.CommonDataDirectory.FullName, ApplicationName);
        return new DirectoryInfo(fullName);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Common to all users, file in application's data directory.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static FileInfo CommonDataFile(params string[] name)
{
    string fullName = Paths.Combine(CommonDataDirectory.FullName, name);
    return new FileInfo(fullName);
}
```

I leave it to you to create the other two, the User's and Program's Directory property and File method.